# Why is a bean declared in @SpringBootApplication class registered even though it is not a stereotyped class?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have this main class in my project

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableOAuth2Sso
public class App 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);    
    }

    @Bean public RequestContextListener requestContextListener(){
        return new RequestContextListener();
    }

}
```

As far as I know, component scan scans beans in **stereotyped** classes which are one of `@Component, @Service, @Repository, @Controller`  if I am not wrong.

From spring docs

> By default, classes annotated with @Component, @Repository, @Service,
>   @Controller, or a custom annotation that itself is annotated with
>   @Component are the only detected candidate components.

I cannot understand how the bean in this class is registered. As it is not a stereotyped class and no annotation is annotated with `@Component` it shouldn't be scanned in the first place but this code works perfectly. In fact for my use case having the bean in this class was the only way my problem was solved, but that is a different thing. Can anyone please explain this. Thanks !!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`@SpringBootApplication`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/SpringBootApplication.java#L50) is a meta annotation which looks like:

```
// Some details omitted
@SpringBootConfiguration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public @interface SpringBootApplication { ... }
```

[`@SpringBootConfiguration`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/SpringBootConfiguration.java#L43) is also a meta annotation:

```
// Other annotations
@Configuration
public @interface SpringBootConfiguration { ... }
```

And [`@Configuration`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-context/src/main/java/org/springframework/context/annotation/Configuration.java#L383) is:

```
// Other annotations
@Component
public @interface Configuration { ... }
```

It works Since:

> By default, classes annotated with @Component, @Repository, @Service,
>   @Controller, or **a custom annotation that itself is annotated with
>   @Component are the only detected candidate components.**

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I can't believe @Component was there, I checked all the annotations, can't understand how I missed it. Still thanks for the help !

Answer (score 2):

This is because `@SpringBootApplication` acts also as a `@Configuration` annotation.

`@Configuration` is used to create define beans as in xml spring configurarion files.

You can have a bean configuration class.

```
@Configuration
class MyConfiguration{
@bean MyBean myBean(){...};
}
```

o you can have a Spring configuration file

```
<beans>
   <bean id="myBean" class="MyBean" />
</beans>
```

In your case you're unsing Spring configuration class as you're using `@SpringBootApplication`

You can see more here

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/spring_java_based_configuration.htm

http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/SpringBootApplication.html

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.2.1.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Configuration.html

Comment: Thanks for the help, yes I somehow missed the meta annotation even though I looked at all the annotations. Thanks for the answer, I have upvoted it but already accepted the first one.